How to add label on each data point based in webgl points layer
I am building a webgl layer using WebGLPointsLayer. I want to add label on each data point. I have used FlatStyle and FlatText to build the style, because we want to apply filter to filter data based on user action.
Below are the example where I have added webGl layer with label. Data point are visible but label are not visible on map.
const vectorSourceWebGl = new Vector({
  url: 'https://d2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net/naturalearth-3.3.0/ne_110m_populated_places.geojson',
  format: new GeoJSON(),
  wrapX: true,
});

const layer = new WebGLPointsLayer({
      source: vectorSourceWebGl,
      style: {
        'circle-radius': 10,
        'circle-fill-color': '#c44231',
        'circle-displacement': [0, 0],
        'circle-opacity': 0.95,
        // 'circle-declutter-mode': 'declutter',
        // Not working
        'text-value': 'Label Me', // ['get', 'NAME'], // Dynamic Label for each point
        'text-font': '12px Arial', // Specify font size and family
        'text-size': 1.2, // Scale factor for text size
        'text-offset': [0, -10], // Position the text above the circle
        'text-color': 'black', // Label color
        'text-opacity': 1.0, // Label opacity
      },
    });

Here is the example : https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/label-on-data-mrvfxh
Can you help to solve this?
Once the label is visible I have to add zoom base label support. For example when user reached zoom level 15 and more only this case want to show labels.
